# Insert Data Into Databse Once User Clicks on Button

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I am trying to write a code that will insert data into a database once user click on button. There's something wrong with the code and it does not seem to work properly. I connect to an external database based on my hosting provider.

```
private void druk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection conn;
            string myConnectionString;

            myConnectionString = "server=s59.hekko.net.pl;uid=truex2_kuba;" +
                "pwd=test;database=truex2_kuba;";

            try
            {
                conn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection(myConnectionString);
                conn.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            }
            catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

                cmd.CommandText = "insert into [barcode]values(@class, @tree, @type, @amount, @length, @width, @square)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@class", klasa.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tree", gatunek.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", rodzaj.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", amount.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@length", length.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@width", width.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@square", textBox1.Text);
                int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (a > 0)

            {
                MessageBox.Show("Zapisane do raportu");
            }
```

Comment: Are you passing the username and password in the connection string?

Comment: what's the error message ?

Comment: Please put the code from below your `catch` block _inside_ the `try` block. This is the code that _executes_ the query and that probalby raises an exception. Then tell us what that exception is.

Comment: And you need to tell your `cmd` to use your `conn` as connection (probably by passin g`conn` to the `MySqlCommand` constructor).

Comment: The error I get is as following: Reading From The Stream Has Failed

Answer (score 1):

The issue is this:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
```

is in the scope of the `try`, `catch` block.

Further on in the code, there was a reference to the `cmd` variable which is null and hence no data goes in.

Move it outside of the `try`, `catch` block.

Comment: I moved this outside the try and catch block but now I get an error  Reading From The Stream Has Failed

Comment: Set the breakpoints at *1* `conn = ...`, *2* `cmd.CommandText = `..., *3* `int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`, Re run the code, tell me what was the result of where the error occurs.